# customize filter or property in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the SQLAlchemy ORM to work with both MySQL and sqlite. Suppose I have a function that will take input from a column of string type and finally return an integer.  The logic of this
function may be complicated that can not be implemented by simply using built-in SQL functions
provided by back-end database engines. I am wondering what is the best way to perform the query based on this function.

Thanks.

Comment: You should concretize your problem. So tou need just a convertion to/from DB or you'd like to filter queries based on this field? For the later provide an example of function too.

Comment: I would like to filter queries based on some function evaluated on a certain field. This function can be an arbitrary used-defined function that returns an integer.

Comment: This is not possible to do database side in general. You have to apply filtering by this function in Python code.

Answer (score 0):

@BingJian You can implement this with the help of [`hybrid` extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).

In hybrid you can define function which will be call when you do filter on that field. You have to handle those operation in functions.